# Failed building wheel for pytorch3d in windows

Tags: pytorch, pytorch3d

i am trying to install pytorch3d on windows 10 following the instruction here

https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d/blob/main/INSTALL.md

i have cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0

my pytorch version is '1.13.0.dev20220616'

i don't know what is CUB build , i have tried may times but can't correclty install it

using `pip install "git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d.git@stable"`

i got following error

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pytorch3d
Running setup.py clean for pytorch3d
Failed to build pytorch3d
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pytorch3d, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

i need simple way to install it or tell me if i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

In requirements, they don't mention nightly versions of pytorch. It could be causing the error. Also, what is your python version?